# Passar um id para outra pagina passando por um foreach

Tags: php

Seguinte: quando o usuario clicar em "candidatar-se", ele ira para outra pagina e la trabalharei com o id do registro que ele clicou, so que ai nasce o problema, nao sei como fazer isso. codigos:

pag_listar_chamado:

```
                            foreach ($chamados as $chamado):
                                    ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['data_solicitado'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['detalhes'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['logradouro'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['estado'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['cidade'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['bairro'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['num'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['complemento'] ?></td>    
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['ddd'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['numero'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['nome'] ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $chamado['sobrenome'] ?></td>
                                    <td><a onclick="verificaAlistamento()">Candidatar-se</a></td>
                                    <?php 
                                        $chamado['id_contrato'];
                                    ?>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            endforeach;
```

pag_verifica

```
    $user = $_SESSION['nome'];
    $idContrato = $_POST[$id_contrato];
    $cpf = pegaCpfUsuarioLogado($conexao, $user);
    if(verificaCandidatura($conexao, $cpf)){
?>
    <script>deuRuim()</script>
<?php
    candidatarSe($conexao, $cpf, $idContrato);
    header("location: pag_menuTecnico.php");
    } else {
?>
    <script>deuBom()</script>
<?php
    header("location: pag_menuTecnico.php");
    }
```

eu ja tentei fazer assim: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/307200-pegar-o-indice-do-array-em-um-foreach/

so que ai parou de trazer os chamados em abertos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É só você salvar na **session**:

**pag_listar_chamado.php**

```
$_SESSION['id_contrato'] = $chamado['id_contrato'];
```

Na outra página, você pode usá-lo normalmente:

**pag_verifica.php**

```
$idContrato = $_SESSION['id_contrato'];
```

---

Ao fim, não esqueça de destruir a sessão com **unset**:

```
session_destroy ();
unset($_SESSION['id_contrato']);
```

Comment: Obrigado!! Resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Disponha, amigo ^^